# How to disable Bluetooth capability with Cordova for iOS to avoid error of missing NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription

Tags: cordova, ios13

I am developing an application for iOS/Android with Cordova, and the application does not have any function to use Bluetooth. Probably after launching iOS 13, I have trouble to publish new version of my app to AppStoreConnect. I have received an alert email from Apple to be noticed that NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key is missing in the info-plist.

As mentioned above, I do not need Bluetooth function for my app, but some of the plugin is using it probably without my intension.

If someone has the same problem, please let me know the solution.

Following is my environment.

Cordova

- Cordova 7.1.0

Plugins

- cordova-admob-sdk 0.22.0 "AdMob SDK"
- cordova-plugin-admob-free 0.25.0 "Cordova AdMob Plugin"
- cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-swift-support 3.1.1 "SwiftSupport"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.4 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
- cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.2 "Toast"
- cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
- cordova-sqlite-storage 2.3.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
- phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
- phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.3 "PushPlugin"

I would like to disable Bluetooth function and make my application to be passed to AppleStoreConnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official statement you'll receive from the review team if this string is missing:

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. **While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required**. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

As mentioned in this statement, it's very likely that one of the plugins you're using references the bluetooth API. And even if you're **not** using this API in your app, you still need to provide the purpose string.

So the easiest and fastest solution (and how I did it myself) is: just provide the string and the review will pass. You can easily add this string to the `*-Info.plist` this using the plugin [`cordova-custom-config`.](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and apologize for late response. I have added the description to config.xml as following.

<platform name="ios">
  <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription">
    <string>xxx</string>
  </edit-config>
</platform>

I have succeeded to publish the app to AppStoreConnect and am waiting for the review.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the problem come from AdMob SDK (cordova-admob-sdk), a dependency of cordova-plugin-admob-free.

Do you know what is the reason of usage (framework CoreBlueTooth in AdMob SDK) please ? Or there is any solution to not use this framework ?

Comment: Please only use the answer form to write direct answers to the question. If you have a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Thank you for your information. As mentioned, cordova-admob-sdk is using Bluetooth function. I have commented out the related code but it could not work. In gitlab the same issue is set but no answer so far.
https://gitlab.com/ratson/cordova-admob-sdk/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the plugin `cordova-admob-sdk` is dependent on the `CoreBluetooth.framework` framework. It would have been nice if we could configure the plugin not to be dependent on the `bluetooth`. So until the plugin fixes that part, we can resolve the issue in two different ways.

**Solution 1:**

One solution is to add a statement saying your app uses `Bluetooth`. It can be configured in your `config.xml`.

```
<platform name="ios">
    ...
    <config-file parent="NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
       <string>
           This app requires access to your bluetooth. blah blah blah
       </string>
    </config-file>
    ...
</platform>
```

**Solution 2:**

The second solution is to remove the dependency on the `CoreBluetooth.framework` by yourself. You could do this from the Xcode. You just need to delete the entry for `CoreBluetooth.framework` under the `General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` section.

[image]